# Prove that the following equation isn't satisfied for any natural number

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Prove that for every $n\in \mathbb{N+}$ the following equation is **not** satisfied:

${{n}\choose {1}}-2\cdot{{n}\choose {3}}+4\cdot {{n}\choose {5}}-8\cdot {{n}\choose {7}}+...\pm2^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\cdot{{n}\choose {k}} = 0$,

where $k$ is the largest odd number not greater than $n$.

I think it's we need to consider 4 cases ($n$ modulo $4$), but I don't know how to finish the proof.

Comment: Is this equivalent to asking whether $(1+\sqrt{-2})^n$ is ever a real number?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Can you expand your answer, show the similarity of those two problems?

Comment: Multiply your equation by $\sqrt{-2}$ and you get: $$0=\sum_{k \text{ odd}}(\sqrt{-2})^k\binom{n}{k}$$ The right side is the imaginary part of $(1+\sqrt{-2})^n$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm sorry but I'm not into abstract algebra. Is it correct to multiply the equation by $\sqrt{-2}$?

Comment: There might be another approach. If $a_n$ is your sum there is a recurrence, $a_{n+1}=2a_n-3a_{n-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for this idea. I know how to continue the proof from this place. But can you tell me how did you get the recurrence. Did you use some method or just noticed it on low values of $n$?